# как csv файл передать в jsp используя spring model

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, dygraph

dygraphs js фрамеворк требует csv файл. Все бы ничего если бы я не использовал фрамеворк в jsp.Как мне передать csv файл в Jsp? Пишу на spring. Надо как то поместить csv в модель и передать.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      g2 = new Dygraph(
      document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
      "сюда передать.csv", // path to CSV file
      {}          // options
     );
    </script>
```